# Canvas OnDraw method

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I am currently creating a maze using a pair of boolean array (horizontal and vertical) in order to draw lines for the maze.

The maze only every displays 5 bools from the array at one time. Then, I have an user who is always centered and as he moves through the maze the next set of bools are drawn. This is working as it should.

The issue that I am having is: when the user moves to a certain part of the maze the for loop drawing the lines becomes higher than the bool array and therefore crashes the app. Please find below some code snippets.

The onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);
    int currentX = maze.getCurrentX(),currentY = maze.getCurrentY();
    int drawSizeX = 6 + currentX;
    int drawSizeY = 6 + currentY;
    currentX = currentX - 2;
    currentY = currentY - 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < drawSizeX - 1; i++)  {
        for(int j = 0; j < drawSizeY - 1; j++)  {
            float x = j * totalCellWidth;
            float y = i * totalCellHeight;
            if(vLines[i + currentY][j + currentX])  {
                canvas.drawLine(x + cellWidth,   //start X
                                y,               //start Y
                                x + cellWidth,   //stop X
                                y + cellHeight,  //stop Y
                                line);
            }
            if(hLines[i + currentY][j + currentX]) {
                canvas.drawLine(x,               //startX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //startY 
                                x + cellWidth,   //stopX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //stopY 
                                line);
            }
        }
        //draw the user ball
        canvas.drawCircle((2 * totalCellWidth)+(cellWidth/2),   //x of center
                          (2 * totalCellHeight)+(cellWidth/2),  //y of center
                          (cellWidth*0.45f),                    //radius
                          ball);
    }
```

EDIT 1 - The Move -

```
public boolean move(int direction) {
    boolean moved = false;
    if(direction == UP) {
        if(currentY != 0 && !horizontalLines[currentY-1][currentX]) {
            currentY--;
            moved = true;
        }
    }
    if(direction == DOWN) {
        if(currentY != sizeY-1 && !horizontalLines[currentY][currentX]) {
            currentY++;
            moved = true;
        }
    }
    if(direction == RIGHT) {
        if(currentX != sizeX-1 && !verticalLines[currentY][currentX]) {
            currentX++;
            moved = true;
        }
    }
    if(direction == LEFT) {
        if(currentX != 0 && !verticalLines[currentY][currentX-1]) {
            currentX--;
            moved = true;
        }
    }
    if(moved) {
        if(currentX == finalX && currentY == finalY) {
            gameComplete = true;
        }
    }
    return moved;
}
```

If there is anything else that I need to clarify please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, is the maze an instance of an Android class or one of your own ? How is computed maze.getCurrentX() ? maze.getCurrentY() ? Regards

Comment: That is all calulated in a seperate calss which defines various things such as size, final position etc. As you can see in the edited code Current X & Y are defined to 0 and then increased and decreased depending on the users movement.

Comment: In your move method, why don't you code, for up direction test for example, if (currentY > 0 && !horizontalLines[currentY-1][currentX]). So using the '>' operator instead of the '!=' operator. This way you will be using a more defensive programming. Perhaps it will not solve your problem, but it can already solve potential future issues.

Comment: Aren't you mixing i and x with j and y?

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE, I made those changes but that did not fix the issue. I have currently got the maze drawing as it should and i can stop the app from crashing by limiting the drawsize to 10/11 (X/Y), this however means the user is not able to pass the 5th block into the 6th block. Any further guidence is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @nininho - the i and js are correct. Please see the above comment to detail my issue/ fix a little more, thanks.

Comment: But you use [i + currentY][j + currentX] for both vLines and hLines but they're not of the same size.

Comment: @nininho, the way the boolean arrays have been setup this is correct, but as i said before this is not my issue as the maze is drawing correctly. I am having an issue with moving the user past the 5th block. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawSizeX/Y indexes over the array when currentX/Y is high enough (length-6)

So limit the values to Math.min(current + 6, array.length)

Comment: I not entirly sure where I should be using this, I have previously tried a if statement within the for loop to limit the drawSize X/Y to 10 & 11. This did stop the app from crashing, however also stopped the user moving past a certain point, in this case could not move to the 6th block to the right. Thanks

Comment: @LandLPartners I think you should post more of your code, otherwise your readers will probably have difficulties to help you.

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE I have added another section of code into my question, these are import bits from the maze class and an additional section the the bool arrays snippet. Thanks

Comment: Where did the exception occured ? (Also, was it a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ?)

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE, Having done a little more debugging I realised that nothing was being triggered after 5 squares. This is due to the fact that I am using SizeY/X = 5. The reason I am using this is for the reason that i only want to display a 5 x 5 block at one time. Therefore, I need to somehow work out another way to display 5x5 and then change that code back to sizeX = horizontalLines[0].length; You can see the example code in the snippet for the maze class. Thanks

Comment: @LandLPartners `if(vLines[i + currentY][j + currentX])`  you could do for example `if (i + currnentY<v.lines.length && j+currentX < vlines[i.currentY].lenght && vLines[i + currentY][j + currentX] )` 
If that was your problem

Comment: @jpa thanks for the fix, however that was not what I was after. I have realised that my onDraw is actually correct and the issue I am having is with the view of my maze. It correctly draws out however as I am restricted the drawSize to 5 blocks when the user reaches this, no futher move functions are triggered. Essentailly, I need to work out a different way to zoom in on the canvas, possibly drawing the whole maze on first load. Thanks

Comment: @jpa the code you speficifed was actually correct in the end I had to make a small edit on my move snippet in order to keep the zoom to 5x5 whilst allowing the user to navigate through the whole maze. Thanks