# Set a zoom for my drawn canvas

Tags: java, android, zooming

I have an application which draws a maze using lines from 2 boolean arrays onto a canvas. I have got this all working as it should, however I need a way to set the zoom so it only ever shows 5x5 instead of the current maze size of 50x50.

A little further information - the user circle will always be in the center of the maze and when he move in any direction the next section of the maze would be displayed. Please view my previous questions for some code snippets which may be useful.

[Previous Question Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310279/android-canvas-ondraw/11311557#comment14905142_11311557)

Any help/ guidence here would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question, I had a small bug within my move where it was checking the against the zoom size instead of the array size.